# Remove a particular character ("-") and characters after it in a column of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string

From my dataframe column, I want to remove the "-" character and the letters following it.

For eg.

Input dataframe

```
Name    Subset
Apple   AP-, GP-
Bat     BT-01A, KL
Cat     CT-L, OK-01
```

Output desired

```
Name    Subset
Apple   AP,GP
Bat     BT,KL
Cat     CT,OK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-[^,]*` to match everything from `-` till a comma, here we use negation `[^,]` to match a non comma character:

```
df['Subset'] =  df.Subset.str.replace('-[^,]*', '', regex=True)

df
    Name  Subset
0  Apple  AP, GP
1    Bat  BT, KL
2    Cat  CT, OK
```

Comment: Best to throw in a `regex=True` there to avoid the `FutureWarning`

Comment: @JonClements Hmm, yeah good point. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

dataFrame = {
    "Name": "Subset",
    "Apple": "AP-", "GP-",
    "Bat": "BT-01A", "KL"
    "Cat": "CT-L", "OK-01"
}

pd.DataFrame(dataFrame).iloc[:, 1].str.split("-", expand=True)[0]
```

Comment: Using this I can only get rid of the "-". Not the characters after it.

Comment: Replace the variable dataFrame with the name of your data object. All the code does is converts to string and replaces the "-" with nothing, thus changing "CT-L" to "CT"

Comment: Sorry now - it removes everything on the line after it

Comment: Thanks - remember to upvote it and accept as answer

Comment: Kindly check the edited question.
My dataset column has comma seprated values, while using the above code, everything after - is sliced.

Comment: What does the data frame look like in Python?

Comment: Please check the dataframe in question. (edited now)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242631/discussion-between-harry-hopkinson-and-shlok-doshi).